# ExtJS AJAX TabPanel tab load event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, dom-events, tabpanel

Is there any way to add an event listener to the load/update event of a ajax based tabpanel in ExtJS v3.3.1? I need an event that fires after the tab content is retrieved and fully rendered, not right after the tab is selected/activated and the loading spinner is displayed.

I thought I would be able to add this event on the Ext.Updater object returned by the tabpanel's `getUpdater()` method, i.e.:

```
myTabs.getUpdater().on('update', function()
{
    console.log('tab loaded');
});
```

But that does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Edit: Here's my full implementation to make it easier to see what I'm trying to do:

```
var myTabs = new Ext.TabPanel( 
{ 
    id : 'rec_tabs', 
    activeTab : 0,    
    enableTabScroll : true, 
    padding : 5, 
    autoWidth : false, 
    autoHeight : true, 
    border : false, 
    plain : true, 
    defaults : { autoHeight: true }, 
    items : 
    [ 
        { title : 'Tab #1',  autoLoad : { url : 'tab1_content.php', scripts : true } }, 
        ... 
    ] 
}); 

myTabs.render('tab_div'); 

myTabs.getUpdater().on('update', function() 
{ 
    console.log('tab loaded'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I hadn't realized that the properties of the "autoLoad" config object for each item of the TabPanel are actually just used as parameters for the Ext.Updater.update() method. So all I had to do was is along with the "url" and "scripts" parameters, is define the "callback" property as a function to be executed when the tab content is finished loading into its body, and its good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
myTabs.on("afterrender", function() {
    console.log('tab loaded');
});
```

Comment: Yeah no good on that either, that fires right after the tab is opened and the spinner is shown.

Comment: There are 5 tabs, all added to the panel using an autoLoad config object setting the url that the content is pulled from, and have the "scripts" property set to true.